# Change data inside string with box brackets

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string

```
garments[0][1]; // The 0 and 1 can be other numbers
```

I need to replace the data inside the second and the third box brackets.

```
[0] and [1]
```

So that it can be

```
garments[4][6]
```

Please let me know your suggestions when you get a chance, thank you.

Comment: Is it always `[0][1]` or can it be different keys? And I assume the `[4]` and `[6]` change?

Comment: it is a string, I want to change the values inside the box brackets onClick

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I'm quite sure this isnt the way to go. Please expand your answer with what the end goal is :)

Comment: @Martijn     It will be different keys all the time

Comment: is garments[n][m] two dimentional array? Or you want just to know how swap characters inside string?

Comment: I am using this as an id on form fields, Its just a string, i would like to change the values inside the brackets onclicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
var string = 'garments[' + 4 + '][' + 6 + ']'; //in your onClick function  
//To increment dynamically:  
var string = 'garments[' + i + '][' + j + ']'; //i and j being variables incrementing in your loops/treatments
```

**Update to address comments:**
If you want to break `"garnments[0][1]"` into `"garnments"`,`0` and `1` you can do the following:

```
var string = "garnments[0][1]";  
string = string.split('['); //string = [["garnments"],["0]"],["1]"]]
string[1].replace(']','');
string[2].replace(']',''); //string = [["garnments"],["0"],["1"]]
```

You can then change values and rebuild your string for further use.

It is a bit brutal though. You can use RegExp as showed by @Diego

Comment: Thx for editing, i'm new to this :).
And yes, it's a bit brutal but you can use variables instead of 4 and 6 to make it dynamic if needed.

Comment: Oh, I would like to get the value inside the box brackets first and then increment it accordingly, I apologies if i did not ask the question correctly.

Comment: Editted again, the first line did nothing but waste resource :)

Comment: also the word garments can change to another word, dynamically

Comment: The structure of the id will be garments[' + 4 + '][' + 6 + '], the idea is to be able to edit the values in the structure.

Comment: for example if value is garments, should be able to change it to shoes, if first box bracket has 3 as value make it 4 .. etc ..

Comment: Or let me rephrase the question, what is the best way to get all 3 values in the string below into different variables

Comment: Or let me rephrase the question, what is the best way to get all 3 values in the string below into different variables
     garments[4][6]

Comment: @Martijn    Or let me rephrase the question, what is the best way to get all 3 values in the string below into different variables garments[4][6]

Comment: There is a split() function. If you split the string on '[', you'll get an array with "garnments", "4]" and "6]". You can then use .replace() to replace "]" by "".

Comment: @Karim M              done, thanks bro :) , this should be faster than regex isnt it ?

Comment: @Manu I don't know if it is faster but I understand it better this way ^^. Did it work for your use?

Comment: @Karim M.        sure it did, quick question though, string.replace would only remove one instance of a character in a string .. is it ? have to run it twice if i have to remove a character that exists twice in the string.. is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
'garments[0][1]'.replace('[0]','[4]').replace('[1]','[6]')
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, what is the best way to get all 3 values in the string below into different variables garments[4][6]

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach.

```js
var string = "['foobar'][2][12]";

var match = 
  /\[([^\]]+)\](?:\[(\d+)\])(?:\[(\d+)\])/g
  .exec(string);
   
console.log(match);
```

Comment: Or let me rephrase the question, what is the best way to get all 3 values in the string below into different variables garments[4][6]

Comment: I have given you my first approach. If you print `match` variable you will see the 3 different values.

Comment: Your approach is working for me perfectly, the only issue is that when i do the below

      alert(match[1]);
      alert(match[2]);
      alert(match[3]);

Just alert(match[1]) has an extra ] with the string, can you help me get rid of it ?

Comment: i apologise, the actual string is  [foobar][2][12], hence the issue

Comment: ['foobar'][2][12]

Answer (score 0):

For any possible string with ***[m][n] format:

```
Function SetNewValues(testString, n, m)
{
    var keyWordLengh = testString.indexOf("[");
    return testString.substring(0,keyWordLengh) + "[" + n.toString() + "][" + m.toString() + "]";

}
```

Where:
testString is entire string to work on, like "something[342][345]"
n,m are values to be put inside brackets :)